# Angularjs multiple urls for same state

Tags: angularjs

Making a verify account page and want to be able to pass an email and auth code via url like so:

```
https://mywebsite.com/verify?email=a@a.com&code=1234
```

It looks like I can't do it this way in angular. And should instead be done like this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/verify/:email/:code
```

And use $stateParams to grab the vars.

Can you have two different URLs trigger the same state? So both URLs below trigger the same state and the controller checks for the vars and does it's magic.

```
https://mywebsite.com/verify
https://mywebsite.com/verify/:email/:code
```

Comment: just mention the same controller and check for $stateParams

Comment: And just make two different states for it? I don't know why, but that seems sloppy to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `configuration` as like below and you can pass the `param` which is `required` to send for the `url`

```
 $stateProvider.state('verify', {
          url: '/verify?email&code',
          templateUrl: 'verify.html',
          controller: 'verifyCtrl'
        });
```

working fiddle: http://plnkr.co/edit/AwHkFj?p=preview

Comment: Quick follow up question... is there a way to pass the vars with something like $state.go(...)?

Comment: Thanks :) You are welcome..yes check $state.transition

Answer (score 1):

Rather than defining the params `email` and `code` as path parameters, you could use search parameters and access them via `$routeParams`.

e.g, your route would be:

```
$routeProvider.when('/verify', routeConfig);
```

the URL would be:

```
https://mywebsite.com/verify?email=a@a.com&code=1234
```

And in the controller, you would inject `$routeParams` and access via:

```
$routeParams[email]; // = a@a.com
$routeParams[code]; // = 1234
```

For more info on `$routeParams`, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: Unfortunately I am using states not routes.

Comment: ah, sorry, I missed that you were using ui-router not ng-route :)